# conda-forge pillow cannot load DLLs

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, conda

Seriously, I have no idea what is up. My minimal working example (Windows 10 Pro, with administrative access, updated as of 2019-11-06):

1. Fresh install of most recent MiniConda (I used "all users")
2. .condarc as per conda-forge:

```
 channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults 
 channel_priority: strict
```

3. conda create --name TEST
4. conda activate TEST
5. conda install pillow
6. python -c "from PIL import Image"

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified
 module could not be found.
```

I'm tearing my hair out here. Things I have tried/noticed:

- Despite using conda-forge strict, the `vc` and `vc2015` packages are installing from pkgs/main.
- I have upgraded by base environment, which triggers a switch to conda-forge python. However, the base environment continues to use `vc` from pkgs/main. (for all I know, this is the correct behavior, but with DLL load failures and vc/vc2015 coming from a different repo than the package, I get suspiscious).
- I have ensured that all paths involved, including base install and my environment install paths, have no spaces.
- The hack of `conda remove pillow --force` then `pip install pillow`...works? It worries me, because I can't figure out why, and I don't know if there will be downstream C incompatibilities
- If the above instructions are repeated, but without the switch to conda forge, no error occurs.

NOTE: `conda remove pillow` does NOT work with `--force`, because it takes ALL the dependent packages with them in a real environment, as well as any unused dependencies now that those packages are removed. The above method with `--force` allows a drop-in replacement of pillow in an otherwise well-formed environment.